# Call c# function for retrieve data from javascript passing javascript variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i'm a new user. Pleased to know all. EHm i'm blocked into task described on title. I'm italian but i can speak english. I have this javascript into page.aspx.

```
<script> 

    // Call template init (optional, but faster if called manually)
    $.template.init();

    // Progress
    $('.demo-progress').progress();

    // Table sort - DataTables
    var table = $('#sorting-advanced');
    table.dataTable({
        'aoColumnDefs': [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 5] }
        ],
        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
        'sDom': '<"dataTables_header"lfr>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
        'fnInitComplete': function (oSettings) {
            // Style length select
            table.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_length select').addClass('select blue-gradient glossy').styleSelect();
            tableStyled = true;
        }
    });


    // Table sort - styled
    $('#sorting-advanced').tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false },
            5: { sorter: false }
        }
    }).on('click', 'tbody td', function (event) {

        // Do not process if something else has been clicked
        if (event.target !== this) {
            return;
        }

        var tr = $(this).parent(),
            row = tr.next('.row-drop'),
            rows;

        // If click on a special row
        if (tr.hasClass('row-drop')) {
            return;
        }

        // If there is already a special row
        if (row.length > 0) {
            // Un-style row
            tr.children().removeClass('anthracite-gradient glossy');

            // Remove row
            row.remove();

            return;
        }

        // Remove existing special rows
        rows = tr.siblings('.row-drop');
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            // Un-style previous rows
            rows.prev().children().removeClass('anthracite-gradient glossy');

            // Remove rows
            rows.remove();
        }

        // Style row
        tr.children().addClass('anthracite-gradient glossy');

        var selectedCertificate = getValue();

        // Add fake row
        $('<tr class="row-drop">' +
            '<td colspan="' + tr.children().length + '">' +
                '<div class="float-right">' +
                    '<button type="submit" class="button glossy mid-margin-right">' +
                        '<span class="button-icon"><span class="icon-mail"></span></span>' +
                        'Send mail' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<button type="submit" class="button glossy">' +
                        '<span class="button-icon red-gradient"><span class="icon-cross"></span></span>' +
                        'Remove' +
                    '</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<strong>Certificate Number: </strong>' + selectedCertificate + '<br>' +
                '<strong>Area: </strong> ' + +' <br>' + function(selectedCertificate, condition)
                '<strong>Email: </strong><br>' + function(selectedCertificate, condition)
                '<strong>Ultimo accesso: </strong>' + function(selectedCertificate, condition) +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>').insertAfter(tr);

    }).on('sortStart', function () {
        var rows = $(this).find('.row-drop');
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            // Un-style previous rows
            rows.prev().children().removeClass('anthracite-gradient glossy');

            // Remove rows
            rows.remove();
        }
    });

</script>
```

And then C# code behind:

```
 protected string function(string certificate, int condition)
{
    if (condition == 0)
        return "data1";
    else
        return "data2";
}
```

How can i call function passin javascript variable and condition value? Thanks very much, any help are apreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax post

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/controller/action(function)",
  data: "{certificate:value, condition: value}",
  success: success,
});
```

or use jquery.post

```
$.post( "url", { certificate:value, condition: value } );
```

Comment: When you need to call this "function" method? for example if you want to call this "function" method when you click on any button then you must call the js function within the js function you need to add this code.